# Is there a rangeselector event to get dates outside the data range?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am looking to build a chart which loads and displays years worth of time-series data, collected over years, but loaded dynamically in small chunks (1 day, 1 week, 1 month).  For instance, I am looking at a chart which is displaying data for 8/21 -> 8/22.

I would like to use the built-in range selector in order to change the date range, for example to change the From date to 8/15, and then go fetch and display data for 8/15 -> 8/22.

I am looking for an event or API which is triggered when the date rangeselector is modified by a user.  I have found and experimented with `xAxis.events. setExtremes`, but this doesn't seem to have what I need.  Before triggering this event, the chart does some form of sanitization, the date I give it is discarded and the To-From dates in the event are normalized to the min-and-max range of the data itself.  For example, suppose I have data loaded into my chart from 8/19 -> 8/22 (3-day window), but I have my chart zoomed in to 8/21 -> 8/22 (1 day).  I would like to see data from 8/15 -> 8/22 so I change the From date to 8/15.  The event that gets fired changes the min I entered to be 8/19, as that is the minimum edge of the existing data, but what I would like is an event that says the date was changed to 8/15.

I have also tried to hack something in using the `rangeSelector.inputDateParser` API, but this is definitely not ideal, and I don't think it will even work, as I can't tell [i]which[/i] date field was edited.

I'm not sure what else to try, but i'm worried I will need to implement/integrate my own custom range selector separately, which I would rather not do.

Here is a jsFiddle using `setExtremes`. (It's from the API docs, not my code, but it's a good representation of what I'm trying to do)

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/events-setextremes/

What I would like to happen is, when I set the From date to '2001-01-01', that the `setExtremes` event (or some other event) returns `2001-01-01` (Or any equivalent in some other format).  But the problem is, it changes 2001 to 2007, because that's the lowest data value, before telling me what value was entered.

Is there any way to detect or trigger an event when I change the date in the range selector to a date outside of the range of the data?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such event in the Highcharts core. However, it can be easily added by wrapping `RangeSelector.prototype.drawInput` and adding these lines of code:

```
// Custom event
H.fireEvent(rangeSelector, 'RSValueProvided', {
  inputValue: inputValue,
  dataMin: dataMin,
  dataMax: dataMax
});
```

After that, you can add a callback function that will be invoked when the event occurs:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var chart = this;

      Highcharts.addEvent(chart.rangeSelector, 'RSValueProvided', function(e) {
        var date = +new Date(e.inputValue);

        if (date < e.dataMin || date > e.dataMax) {
          console.log(e.inputValue);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cf0h8tp5/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.fireEvent%3CT%3E
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.addEvent%3CT%3E

Comment: How would I achieve the same behaviour if I'm using Highcharts react?

Comment: You have to add the same code to wrap the `Highcharts.RangeSelector.prototype.drawInput` method. It can be added in the new file and initialized in your component the same as any other module, docs: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#how-to-add-a-module